# Tinytex can't install missing LaTeX package because it is already installed

Tags: r, xelatex, tinytex

My colleague gets the error below when rendering an Rmd to pdf. tinytex can't find an sty file, tries to install it and fails because it is already installed?

I'm puzzled on how to solve this. Suggestions are welcome.

````
"C:/R/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS Tuininsecten.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output Tuininsecten.tex --self-contained --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --variable graphics --variable "geometry:margin=1in" --include-in-header "C:\Users\DIRK_M~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpQJewV9\rmarkdown-str714276548a6.html"
tlmgr.pl: package repository http://mirror.koddos.net/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
tlmgr.pl install: package already present: pdftexcmds
! LaTeX Error: File `pdftexcmds.sty' not found.

! Emergency stop.
<read *>

Error: LaTeX failed to compile Tuininsecten.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Tuininsecten.log for more info.
In addition: There were 11 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
Execution halted```
````

Comment: Did you try removing and re-installing the package?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/552079/latex-error-file-pdftexcmds-sty-not-found

Comment: Good suggestion. Will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-installing TinyTex itself (not the R package) solved the problem.

```
tinytex::reinstall_tinytex()
```

Thanks to [Steffen Moritz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6332958/steffen-moritz) for the suggestion.